# Map function React

Tags: reactjs

I have a grouped object. Then I exchanged the object for the array:
`const objectToArray = ["Since", Array(7)]`. Then I want to map the array to get it `objectToArray[0]` (shows picture) and `objectToArray[1]` (shows list of question). I want to show the category photo and the list of questions below.

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash';
import QuestionsListItem from './QuestionListItem';

const images = require.context('../../img', true);
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true);

const QuestionsList = ({ questions }) => {
  const groupByList = groupBy(questions.questions, 'type');
  const objectToArray = Object.entries(groupByList);

  const questionListItem = objectToArray.map((array) => (
    <img src={imagePath(`./${array[0]}.png`)} alt="star" />,
    array[1].map((question) => (
      <QuestionsListItem
        key={question.id}
        question={question}
      />
    ))));


  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        { questionListItem }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code shows me a error:
`Line 14:  Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences` This is it `<img src={imagePath(`./${array[0]}.png`)} alt="star" />,`

When you delete a comma, it gets an error

```
  Line 15:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  13 |   const questionListItem = objectToArray.map((array) => (
  14 |     <img src={imagePath(`./${array[0]}.png`)} alt="star" />
> 15 |     array[1].map((question) => (
     |     ^
  16 |       <QuestionsListItem
  17 |         key={question.id}
  18 |         question={question}
```

How to solve this problem?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here, one `img` for each item in the array?

Comment: @Colin yes, i want render one img for one array. I have a few categories of questions. this is my data ["Since", Array(7)], ["Fashion", Array(7)], ["Math", Array(7)], ["Nature", Array(7)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of an obscure error, but the way you have it now, you'd be returning multiple nodes at the same level, so you need to wrap it with something.

Try this:

```
const questionListItem = objectToArray.map(array => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <img src={imagePath(`./${array[0]}.png`)} alt="star" />
    array[1].map((question) => (
    <QuestionsListItem key={question.id} question={question} />)
  </React.Fragment>
));
```